# Comments deactivated

Tags: comments, activation

I can't write comments to new articles (no `add comment` link available). I use Wordpress 3.4.

I checked the discussion properties and they are set to

- allow guests to comment articles
- none of the other (relevant) options are checked

I have the feeling that comments aren't available since I installed some plugins. But I tried deactivating some with no success in activating comments again.

Suggestions?

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to TwentyEleven. Does it still happen?

Comment: I did that and in the articles is a text now: `comments are closed`.

Comment: Write a new post, enable the _discussion_ meta box and make sure comments are enabled. Still no change on the front-end?

Comment: Now I can leave a comment in the article. But I did not change anything and there are no settings I can make on the `new article` page about comments.

Comment: You have to _activate_ the discussion meta box. In a German WP it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/sktNd.png

Comment: I don't have `discussion` checkbox [there](http://i.imgur.com/Cc6e5.png). Only `last comments`.

Comment: That are the Dashboard screen options, we are talking about the _new post_ page `wp-admin/post-new.php` …

Comment: Ah. I see. I checked the `discussion` checkbox and activated my theme and plugins again and it works now. Thanks. If you write that in a short answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments might have been closed once. If you change this option later globally it doesn’t affect existing posts when comments were turned off per post. To test if comments really work create a new post and enable the *discussion* meta box on that screen:

[image]

If you can comment while all plugins are disabled and the theme is TwentyEleven (default) – then everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

@toscho is right, you might have been disabled the comments for individual posts.

However if you want to enable comments for all your old posts you accidentally disabled, you can use following MySQL query to do it once instead editing each post manually.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status = 'open' WHERE post_type = 'post'
```

**Notice** - This will enable comments for all your posts not the pages.

**Warning** - Don't forget to backup your database before using this query.